# Print body in handler from post request in spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am completely new to Reactive Spring Webflux.
I am writing a handler for a Post request which should

1. Accept Json body(Employee id, name and role),
2. Fetch some more Employee details from database 1 using id field,
3. Return Employee json back with additional attributes like age and dept..

My router code is below:

```
 @Bean       
        -- something like this       
       POST("/empl/create").and(contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)), emplHandler::getMoreEmplDetails
```

Post Body:

```
   {
         "id":"213"
         "name": "John",
         "role": "Manager"
    }
```

Model Class looks like this

```
Public class Employee    
    {
       Public string  id;
       Public string name;
       Public string role;
       Public string dept;
       Public int age;
    }
```

Handler Code is Below

```
public Mono<ServerResponse>getMoreEmplDetails(ServerRequest request){
               Mono<Employee> np = request.bodyToMono(Employee.class);
               np.subscribe(x-> System.out.println("Print Body"+x)); 
                                                            //This returns a MonoOnErrorResume

                       /* More code should follow here*/

Return Mono.empty()// THIS IS TEMPORARY. I WANT TO RETURN COMPLETE EMPL JSON WITH AGE AND DEPT HERE
};
```

Problem is I want to print body for debugging purpose but Keep getting MonoOnErrorResume as indicated in comments in handler code. How do I make sure that my Body was received fine by the handler method   ??

Comment: Hi, if you want to get the actual body you can write request.bodyToMono(Employee.class).block()

Comment: @M.chris I tried that but the error I got was - block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3

Comment: You should never block in a non blocking framework and the one who is subscribing is the one initiated the call so in your case the calling client. If you want to log something, you can do it in either a `flatMap`, `map` or any of the `doOn` operators that are used for side effect. Like `doOnComplete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use map to log the results.

```
Mono<Employee> np = request.bodyToMono(Employee.class);
np.map(s->system.out.println(s));
```